# @Before aspect is not reflecting the modified values in the actual service method

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a service method as below. I have implemented the `@Before` aspect, where the string argument is trimmed based on certain conditions, but when the control is returned back to service method from aspect, the modified values are not reflecting.

I want that the trimmed dataNumber should go to db; Earlier it was working fine, but as of ceratin it stopped working. I have debugged my code, the control is first going inside service method and then it goes to aspect, trim the dataNumber and then control return back to service method but the method arguments doesnot has trimmed value.

```java
@Override
public List<Data> getDataByDataNo(String dataNumber, boolean trim) {
    return getDataByDataNoFromDB(dataNumber, trim);
}
```

Below is aspect :

```java
@Aspect
public class TrimDataAspect{
@Before("execution(* com.impl..DataServiceImpl.getDataByDataNo(..)) && args(String,boolean,..)")
public void intrecept(JoinPoint jp) {
    String dataNumber = (String) jp.getArgs()[0];
    if((boolean) jp.getArgs()[1]){
        dataNumber = dataNumber.substring(12);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify method arguments in a `@Before` or `@After` advice, you need `@Around` in order to do that.

I made up a simple example in pure AspectJ, but it works the same way in Spring AOP:

```java
package com.impl.whatever;

public class Data {
  private String name;

  public Data(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Data(name=" + name + ")";
  }
}
```

```java
package com.impl.whatever;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataServiceImpl {
  public List<Data> getDataByDataNo(String dataNumber, boolean trim) {
    return getDataByDataNoFromDB(dataNumber, trim);
  }

  public List<Data> getDataByDataNoFromDB(String dataNumber, boolean trim) {
    System.out.println("dataNumber = " + dataNumber);
    List<Data> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(new Data("one"));
    result.add(new Data("two"));
    if (!trim)
      result.add(new Data("three"));
    return result;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new DataServiceImpl().getDataByDataNo("Trim, baby! Don't trim this!", false));
    System.out.println(new DataServiceImpl().getDataByDataNo("Trim, baby! Don't trim this!", true));
  }
}
```

Please note how the aspect binds the method parameters to advice parameters in order to avoid usage of `getArgs(..)` and ugly casts.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class TrimDataAspect {
  @Around("execution(* com.impl..DataServiceImpl.getDataByDataNo(..)) && args(dataNumber, trim, ..)")
  public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, String dataNumber, boolean trim) throws Throwable {
    if (trim)
      dataNumber = dataNumber.substring(12);
    return jp.proceed(new Object[] { dataNumber, trim });
  }
}
```

The console log:

```
dataNumber = Trim, baby! Don't trim this!
[Data(name=one), Data(name=two), Data(name=three)]
dataNumber = Don't trim this!
[Data(name=one), Data(name=two)]
```